# How can I find out where in a file the Python file read() method fails? (ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:)

Tags: python, python-3.x, runtime-error

I am using an old Python code to process data files.  The files are results from long calculations.  Sometimes the calculations need to be restarted and that can mess up the file formatting.  Then the Python post-processing code fails.

I'm stuck because the Python post-processing code fails for several files and I can't figure out where in each file to look for a problem.  The files are so large that it's impossible to check each line by hand.

Here's an example of the kind of error I'm seeing:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/mtn/storage/software/languages/anaconda/Anaconda3-2018.12/lib/python3.7/site-packages/asere/io/extxyz.py", line 593, in read_xyz
        nentities = int(line)
    ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "postprocess.py", line 24, in <module>
    path = read('%s%s' % (filename, fileext) , format='xyz', index=':')
```

So it looks like the Python code is failing here, which is useful because now at least I know which file to look in for the formatting problem (the one with extension, "xyz."

```
path = read('%s%s' % (filename, fileext) , format='xyz', index=':').
```

What I would like to know is how to print the line of the file where the failure occurs.  I'm guessing that if I could print "index", then that would tell me the line/time step number.

I tried doing a "print("index")" after the "path" command but the failure happens during the Path" command and before my "print."  Does anyone know how to deal with this?

Comment: There really isn't a good one size fits all solution for debugging problems inside libraries you use. As a first approximation, maybe add a `try`/`except` handler around the problematic call where at least you can print which file it was processing when the error happened. In the end, you might have to refactor the problematic library until it exposes the information you need to debug problems inside it.

Comment: @tripleee, thank you.  I did try your suggestion--adding a try/except.  It isn't  generating any output though.  I know (from previous experience where it was easier to spot the problem) that there will be a formatting problem in a particular time step, where only part of the time step has been printed.  I just can't figure out where in the file the problem time step is though.  If anyone has an inspiration, I'd love to hear it!  Thanks.